# What is the minimum air velocity for a particle to lift vertically?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, drag, flow

I'm trying to design a ventilation system for a production room containing cheese powder. If the return air vent is 2 meters above the machine containing the cheese powder, what is the equation for the maximum velocity allowable for the powder to not be sucked in to the vent?

Vent size is arbitrary and up for design as well.

Answer (score 0):

You drop the object (cheese powder in this case) from significant height. Let it fall and measure its terminal speed. Terminal velocity is the speed at which air resistance balances weight of the body and it stops accelerating, and thereafter it falls with constant speed.

Terminal velocity of the object would be pretty close (if not exactly same) to the flow speed you are looking for. Starting with that, you can use trial and error to find the right speed for your purpose. This will be the speed of air flow where the cheese powder is, not the speed of exhaust, because the cross section of two can be different. You would want to consider the ratio of cross sections in order to get your starting point. For example, if terminal speed is 10, exhaust cross section is 5 and cross section of the flow (where powder is) is 4 times, i.e. 20, you would start with exhaust speed 4 times terminal speed, ie. 40.

By the way, you are looking for maximum, not minimum.